# Load, rotate and replace images with Python using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I just started using the PIL library in python and I am trying to use the image module to load, rotate and replace an Image. I want to do this for all the png:s in all the subdirectories of the folder witch the script is run in.

I have tried using the save function on an image object and passing it the original files' names. The problem is that the files look exactly the same and are all saved in the same directory as the script.

```py
from PIL import Image
import os

for current_directory, sub_directory_names, file_names in os.walk("."):
    for name in file_names:
        if name.endswith(".png"):
            image_path = os.path.join(current_directory, name)
            image = Image.open(image_path)
            image.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)
            image.save(name)
```

The output is all the images in the same directory as the code and not rotated. What I am trying to do is replacing all the images with a rotated version of themselves.

Comment: `transpose` returns a copy of the image, you need to reassign it to another variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just change 2 things in the code to make it works as expected :

- assign the returned value of the method [`transpose`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.transpose) or [`rotate`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.rotate)  to another variable
- give the `image_path` you're already using above to save each image in the right folder

---

```
from PIL import Image
import os

for current_directory, sub_directory_names, file_names in os.walk("."):
    for name in file_names:
        if name.endswith(".png"):
            image_path = os.path.join(current_directory, name)
            image = Image.open(image_path)
            # image_out = image.transpose(Image.ROTATE_90)
            image_out = image.rotate(90)
            image_out.save(image_path)
```